# How to set user properties in firebase analytics for flutter web?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics, flutter-web

I am using [this package](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart) (version 7.2.1) in some flutter web projects and I need to set some user properties in firebase analytics. (BTW, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59739455/2469583) which provided me a way to use firebase analytics in the first place)

There is [this method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase/Analytics/setUserProperties.html), which I believe doesn't work. Or at least I can't figure out how to use because I couldn't find a way to instantiate [this class](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-dart/blob/4156b3eb120a7014bfde8c2af585755e3bade5f1/lib/src/interop/analytics_interop.dart#L28).

Answer (score 0):

From the version [7.2.2-dev](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase#722-dev) we can send the user properties